# Rails 3.1 engine rake task doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I created a new engine with Rails 3.1.rc1

```
➜ (ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3-pre) rails git:(master) be bin/rails plugin new ../first_engine --mountable
rails g scaffold project title:string
```

Scaffold is generated and now when I run

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'app:db:migrate'

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Before rc1, it was working. But what happened now? I couldn't figure it out!

Here is the gist with all the steps and backtraces https://gist.github.com/990641
Can anyone put me the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you Gemfile or RVM Global Gemset file. Change rake to include the version. e.g.

```
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

Just using rake will not work until Rails comes out with a fix. Let us know how you get on. All the best.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Rails 3.1.rc6. I've tried Rake 0.8.7 (with bundle exec rake) and 0.9.2. Is this issue in the Rails bug tracker? Is there somewhere I can find more information?